# Postfix daily limit

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp

I have already created an settled up server with postfix. Now I want to know how many emails can I send a day using postfix from my server. Is there any sending limit like Gmail SMTP(100 Emails a day)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are in control of what is sent from your server. Gmail's limitations are part of its service to prevent abuse. However, what you may find is that receiving servers (particularly Gmail) may limit your inbound mail if you are abusing it in any way.

Comment: Also the original poster should check his/her agreement with the network connection provider: the agreement may include an Acceptable Use Policy. Excessive mass emailing might well be an AUP violation, which may allow the provider to immediately terminate the service with no refund.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that **you do have** unofficial, of-the-record and very, very, very important limits in sending emails to ESP giants like Google, Microsoft and Yahoo, and probably more.

While you are limited only by hardware performance and your ISP's network infrastructure (and possibly policy) in terms of sending emails with Postfix (to extend Simon Greenwood's answer) "giant ESPs" and some spam protection software can induce you more trouble than you asked for if you do not keep your server from sending at some reasonable rate.

I suggest you read awesome [Postfix rate limiting – Politeness goes a long way](http://steam.io/2013/04/01/postfix-rate-limiting/) article to get some usable info.